# Why did Grewishka mention "fate" here?

Tags: alita-battle-angel

In [Alita Battle Angel (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alita:_Battle_Angel),  Grewishka wounds Alita, who is about to kill Vector, and says:

> Grewishka: I knew you wouldn't wait for your **fate** to find you, little
>   flea.

Why did Grewiskha mention "fate" here?

Comment: Because she's fated to die doing something stupid? And she appears to be rushing headlong into bad decision...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fate Grewishka is referring to here is Alita's death at his hands. In their [first encounter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSCrqaXEsZw) he says, "come here, little flea, so I can pinch your head off." (7:25 in clip)

During their [second fight in the underground](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VXa2eCH6Ls), Grewishka references Alita having a predetermined path again. Saying, "But I was saved. Remade. By the same hand that shapes your **destiny** even now." (0:45 in clip) He is referring to Nova, who previously said "rebuild Grewishka... have him bring her to me... dead."

When Grewishka says, "I knew you wouldn't wait for your fate to find you", Alita has come to attack Vector's building. He is basically saying he knew she wouldn't hide from him and wait for him to come after her. She has come to face her "fate" head on. He was wrong about Alita's fate, but correctly assessed her as someone to not shy from a battle.